How to create a carousel component similar to the Microsoft Store carousel using Fluent UI 9?

I'm trying to create a carousel component that closely resembles the Microsoft Store carousel using Fluent UI 9. However, I'm facing difficulties in achieving the exact same visual effects and interactions.
Here are some specific challenges I'm encountering:

Card Hover Effect: I'm unable to replicate the subtle card elevation and shadow changes on hover, as seen in the Microsoft Store carousel.

Card Scaling: I'm not able to achieve the desired card scaling effect when selecting a card.
I've tried the following approaches:



Using FluentUI.React.Carousel: While this component provides a basic carousel functionality, it lacks the specific customizations needed to match the Microsoft Store's design.
Customizing CSS and JavaScript: I've attempted to manually style and animate the carousel, but the results haven't been as polished as the Microsoft Store's.
Is there a specific approach or technique that can be used to achieve the desired look and feel?

here is some of my attempts to do that
import React, { useState } from "react"
import {
  Carousel,
  CarouselCard,
  CarouselNavContainer,
  CarouselNavButton,
  CarouselViewport,
  CarouselSlider,
} from "@fluentui/react-components"

const slides = [
  { id: 1, title: "Slide 1", description: "This is the first slide" },
  { id: 2, title: "Slide 2", description: "This is the second slide" },
  { id: 3, title: "Slide 3", description: "This is the third slide" },
  { id: 4, title: "Slide 4", description: "This is the fourth slide" },
  { id: 5, title: "Slide 5", description: "This is the fifth slide" },
]

export const MicrosoftStyleCarousel: React.FC = () => {
  const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0)
  const [translate, setTranslate] = useState("")

  // Handle slide change
  const goToSlide = (index: number) => {
    translateX(activeSlide, index, 700, 0, 5)
    console.log(translate)
    setActiveSlide(index)
  }

  function translateX(
    active: number,
    target: number,
    baseSize: number,
    slideSize: number,
    totalSlides: number
  ) {
    // If the target is already active, no translation is needed
    if (target === active) {
      setTranslate("")
      return null
    }

    // Calculate current position and direction
    const current = active % totalSlides
    const direction = Math.sign(target - current) // 1 for forward, -1 for backward

    // Calculate the offset
    const distance = target - current - direction * 1
    const offset = distance * slideSize + baseSize

    // Return the translate-x class based on direction
    return direction > 0
      ? setTranslate(`-translate-x-[${offset}px]`)
      : setTranslate(`translate-x-[${offset}px]`)
  }

  return (
    <Carousel motion="fade" circular={true}>
      <CarouselViewport>
        <CarouselSlider
          className={`${translate} duration-400 ease-in-out gap-3`}
          cardFocus
        >
          {slides.map((slide, index) => (
            <CarouselCard
              autoSize
              key={slide.id}
              aria-label={`Slide ${index + 1}`}
            >
              <div
                onClick={() => goToSlide(index)}
                className={`transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out cursor-pointer
                  ${
                    activeSlide === index
                      ? "w-[700px] h-[500px]"
                      : "w-[200px] h-[500px]"
                  }
                  bg-gray-200 shadow-md flex flex-col justify-center items-center rounded-lg`}
              >
                <h2 className="text-lg font-bold">{slide.title}</h2>
                <p className="text-sm text-gray-600">{slide.description}</p>
              </div>
            </CarouselCard>
          ))}
        </CarouselSlider>
      </CarouselViewport>

      {/* Navigation Controls */}
      <CarouselNavContainer layout="inline">
        <div className="flex gap-2 mt-4">
          {slides.map((_, index) => (
            <CarouselNavButton
              key={index}
              onClick={() => goToSlide(index)}
              className={`w-3 h-3 rounded-full border ${
                activeSlide === index
                  ? "bg-blue-500 border-blue-700"
                  : "bg-gray-300 border-gray-400"
              }`}
              aria-label={`Go to slide ${index + 1}`}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </CarouselNavContainer>
    </Carousel>
  )
}

